# $X$ is a quasi-separated scheme iff the intersection $U_a \cap U_b$ is quasicompact for $U_a, U_b$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

[image]
I don't understand the argument in (c) implies (a) of this proof. Why is it that "it suffices that ... is quasicompact."

This is Proposition I.2.7 of EGA IV, Chapter IV, *Etude Locale des Schemas et des Morphismes de Schemas*.

I don't exactly know what 1.1.1 is a reference to here. The most relevant thing I see in that section is the point that if a map $f : X\to Y$ is locally quasicompact (i.e. $Y$ admits an open cover by $\left\{U_i\right\}$ such that $f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is quasicompact) it is quasicompact. But I'm not sure how this helps us here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the proof has a gap, and this has been complained about on this website at least once before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484752/concentrated-schemes-are-closed-under-finite-gluings) (though there are some extra assumptions in that post which are not made here, so the proposed solution is not quite applicable for you).

If you assume that the $U_\alpha$ are affine, then this is proven at the Stacks Project in [tag 01K4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01K4), though as you note in your answer, any quasi-compact but not quasi-separated scheme like $\Bbb A^\infty_k$ with a doubled origin is a counterexample to this claim by taking the trivial open cover.

Here's the lemma and proof transcribed for posterity:

> **Lemma** (Stacks [01K4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01K4)): Let $f:X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f:X\to S$ is quasi-compact,
> 2. the inverse image of every affine open is quasi-compact,
> 3. there exists some affine open covering $S=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ such that $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is quasi-compact for all $i$.

> **Proof**. Suppose we are given a covering $S=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ as in (3). First, let $U\subset S$ be any affine open. For any $u\in U$ we can find an index $i(u)\in I$ such that $u\in U_{i(u)}$. As standard opens form a basis for the topology on $U_{i(u)}$ we can find $W_u\subset U\cap U_{i(u)}$ which is standard open in $U_{i(u)}$. By compactness we can find finitely many points $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in U$ such that $U=\bigcup^n_{j=1} W_{u_j}$. For each $j$ write $f^{−1}(U_{i(uj)})=\bigcup_{k\in K_j} V_{jk }$ as a finite union of affine opens. Since $W_{uj}\subset U_{i(uj)}$ is a standard open we see that $f^{−1}(W_{u_j})\cap V_{jk}$ is a standard open of $V_{jk}$, see [Algebra, Lemma 10.16.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00E2). Hence $f^{−1}(W_{u_j})\cap V_{jk}$ is affine, and so $f^{−1}(W_{u_j})$ is a finite union of affines. This proves that the inverse image of any affine open is a finite union of affine opens.
>
> Next, assume that the inverse image of every affine open is a finite union of affine opens. Let $K\subset S$ be any quasi-compact open. Since $S$ has a basis of the topology consisting of affine opens we see that $K$ is a finite union of affine opens. Hence the inverse image of $K$ is a finite union of affine opens. Hence $f$ is quasi-compact.
>
> Finally, assume that $f$ is quasi-compact. In this case the argument of the previous paragraph shows that the inverse image of any affine is a finite union of affine opens.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is incorrect as stated. Condition (c) does not imply condition (a).

Suppose $X$ is a quasi-compact scheme, and let $\{X\}$ be the open cover of $X$ which has only one element, the whole space $X$. Then certainly $X\cap X$ is quasi-compact, so this is a cover satisfying the hypotheses of (c). So according to the theorem, $X$ should be quasi-separated.

However, this is incorrect. It is known that there exist quasi-compact schemes which are not quasi-separated.